# How to get innerHtml by css/jquery extractor for JMeter

Tags: jquery, html, jmeter

I have a `html SELECT` like this

```
<select id="alias" name="alias">
 <option value="">-Select-</option>
 <option value='100'>testBeneficiary-1</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the `innerHTML` of second `option` by `css/jquery extractor` of `JMeter` which is "testBeneficiary-1" in the above code snippet. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Feel free to wander around this guide on css jquery extractor: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/13/jmeter-css-jquery-extractor/

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the field "Attribute" empty, then it will return inner html.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$( "#alias option:selected" ).text();
```

This will return the string "" instead of value.

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7SP96/)

You can read about using select [learn jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)

Comment: have a look at this, might help http://immikes.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/using-cssjquery-extractor-in-jmeter.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is solvable by `css/JQuery extractor` of `JMeter` or not. But I have solved this this by `Xpath Extractor` of `JMeter`. The following expression works fine to extract the required `innerHTML`.

```
//select[@id='alias']//option[2]//text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Populate your CSS/JQuery Extractor as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `test`
- CSS/JQuery expression: `select[id=alias] option[value=100]`

Other fields can be left blank.

If you use a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) you'll see that `test` variable has `testBeneficiary-1` value. You can also test your CSS/JQuery expressions right in [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for detailed walkthrough on identifying errors in your JMeter script.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In your case:
- use `[id="alias"] option[selected="selected"]`  in CSS/Query expression